# Web Scrabbing text strip

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying the getting prices and products from brands website using Python and Beautifulsoup. 
It is a really small code. 
Some brands has both sale and old prices. I wanted to put them different columns. 
My code working on commandline but when I write it on SublimeText then trying to working it causes error.

my_url = 'https://www.mavi.com/kadin/elbise/c/1'

### #

```
**old_price = contain.strike
old = old_price.sub.strip()**
```

Comment: could you specify the error you got ?

Comment: Please add relevant code and the error that you are getting.

Comment: `works on shell, but not in sublime`

-> check indentation of your code

http://pymbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/thebeginning.html#whitespaces-and-indentation